# How does de-referencing a pointer after casting to int ** change the value to which it points?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int *previous, *current ;
  int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  current =(int *) a ;
  previous = current ;
  current = *( (int**) current ) ; //my question is on this line

  printf ("\nprevious is 0x%x and current is 0x%x \n ", previous , current ) ;
  printf ("\nprev+1 0x%x ,  prev+4 0x%x \n", previous+1 , previous+4 ) ;
return 0;
}
```

and the output is :

```
bash-3.00$ ./a.out

previous is 0xffffd0f8 and current is 0x1

prev+1 0xffffd0fc ,  prev+4 0xffffd108
```

My question is:  "current" was previously pointing to the start of the array, before it was referenced and dereferenced back again. How does the following statement change the value of "current"?

```
current = *( (int**) current ) ;
```

Also, if I print *previous it will print 1 while *current will core dump.  What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Why do you think you're taking a reference to the array? You're not using the `&` operator anywhere in your code.

Comment: @ecatmur Even if I use & operator to access the start of the array in current , I will hit the same issue. My question is basically in the line I mentioned , where the current is casted as int ** and then we dereference the value at current, causing the confusion.

Comment: So why do you mention referencing in the title of the question?

Comment: @ecatmur Edited the question , that was a suggested edit by a user, so I went ahead with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
current = *( (int**) current ) ;
```

First, you cast `current` to an `int**`, so the value stored in the `sizeof(int**)` bytes starting at `&current` are to be interpreted as the address of an `int*`. Then you dereference the pointer obtained from the cast. That means, the `int**` assumed to be stored there is followed, and the `sizeof(int*)` bytes at that address are stored in `current`.

Now, `current` pointed to the first element of the array `a`, so the bytes stored at the beginning of `a` are copied into `current`. If `sizeof(int*) == sizeof(int)`, the `int` value 1 stored in `a[0]` is then interpreted as an address. If `sizeof(int*) == 2*sizeof(int)` (the other common occurrence), then the pointer value is composed of the two `int`s 1 and 2.

`previous` points to the first element of `a`, so dereferencing `previous` yields the value 1. Dereferencing `current` now tries to read an `int` from address 1 (it is undefined behaviour, so whatever else would happen wouldn't violate the standard, but that's the normal course of things), which normally isn't accessible for the process.

Answer (score 2):

```
current =(int *) a ;
```

leaves `current` pointing to a memory address containing the value `1`.  Therefore

```
(int**) current
```

treats this `1` value itself as a pointer, and dereferencing that will unsurprisingly lead to a segfault.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
(int **) current
```

is not dereferencing and this

```
*(ptr)
```

is not referencing.

**Dereferencing**

```
*current
```

Referencing

```
&(ptr)
```

**Final Statement:**

```
current = &(*current);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is dead simple: you are just dereferencing current, so

```
*((int**) current)
```

is the first element of array (which is 0x1) cast to int*.

Dereferencing 0x1 will obviously cause segfault, because in 99.9% of systems this address is not readable by user process.